# Filtering on a value computed using a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

This query works :

```
select r.id, name, description, private, auth,
(select count (*) from message m where m.room = r.id) as messageCount
from room r left join room_auth a on a.room=r.id and a.player='11'
where private is false or auth is not null;
```

This one doesn't :

```
select r.id, name, description, private, auth,
(select count (*) from message m where m.room = r.id) as messageCount
from room r left join room_auth a on a.room=r.id and a.player='11'
where private is false or auth is not null or messageCount>1000;
```

I got this error :

```
ERREUR:  the « messageCount » column doesn't exit
```

How can I cleanly and efficiently add a condition on `messageCount` ? Or more generally how to achieve the intended result (due to the number of columns in the `room` table and the join, I'm not really enthousiastic for a query which would directly query the `message` table and group by `room`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the subquery to the where clause:

```
select sometable.id from sometable
where id in (select id from someothertable)
```

Example fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/02c79/1

Applied to your query:

```
select 
  r.id, 
  name, 
  description, 
  private, 
  auth, 
  (select count (*) from message m where m.room = r.id) as messageCount
from room r 
  left join room_auth a on a.room = r.id and a.player = '11'
where 
  private is false or 
  auth is not null or 
  (select count (*) from message m where m.room = r.id) > 1000;
```

(disclaimer - not sure if this will work perfectly since I'm a MSSQL man so there may be some caveats in Postgre)

Answer (score 3):

The stuff in `select` is evaluated *after* the `from` and `where` (and, best I recollect, `group by` and `having`, or at least did until recent versions of Postgres).

You need to enter the full subquery in the where clause too, since the column is undefined when you reference it:

```
select r.id, name, description, private, auth,
(select count (*) from message m where m.room = r.id) as messageCount
from room r left join room_auth a on a.room=r.id and a.player='11'
where private is false or auth is not null
   or (select count (*) from message m where m.room = r.id)>1000;
```

You could also use a `join` / `group by` / `having` clause to do the same while avoiding the correlated subquery, since the latter will perform terribly.

Lastly, you could — and, in fact, should — maintain the count in your room using e.g. a trigger. That way you'll be able to put an index on it and use an OR'ed bitmap index scan to fetch your rows if you've indexes on `private` and `auth` too.

Comment: Too bad you were 5 minutes late ;)

Comment: Ya, I saw, but I do add more info. ;-)